# If $n(n+1)a_{n+1}=n(n-1)a_{n}-(n-2)a_{n-1}.$ >Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $a_{0}=1,a_{1}=2$ and for $n\geq 1\;, n(n+1)a_{n+1}=n(n-1)a_{n}-(n-2)a_{n-1}.$
>
> Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}$

$\bf{Attempt:}$ $2a_{2} = a_{0} = 1$ so $\displaystyle a_{2} = \frac{1}{2}$

$\displaystyle 6a_{3}=2a_{2} = 1$ so $\displaystyle a_{3} = \frac{1}{6}$

could some help me to solve it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Working through the first few $n$ values it can be seen that, for $n \geq 2$,
$$a_{n} = \frac{a_{0}}{n!}.$$
This yields the limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{0}}{n!} = 0.$$

For verification:
\begin{align}
\frac{n(n+1) a_{n+1} - (n-1) a_{n}}{(n+1)(n+2)} &= \frac{a_{0} \, (n - (n-1))}{(n+2)!} = \frac{a_{0}}{(n+2)!} = a_{n+2}. 
\end{align}

Comment: You should include the induction base, as for the first two terms $a_0, a_1$ the induction hypotheses is not met

Answer (score 0):

$$n(n+1)a_{n+1}=n(n-1)a_n-(n-2)a_{n-1}$$

Multiplying both sides by $(n-1)!$, we get,

$$(n+1)!a_{n+1}=n!(n-1)a_n-(n-1)!(n-2)a_{n-1}$$

Now, denoting $b_n:=n!\cdot a_n$, we rewrite the above as,

$$b_{n+1}=(n-1)b_n-(n-2)b_{n-1}$$

Rewriting,

$$b_{n+1}-b_n=n(b_n-b_{n-1})-2(b_n-b_{n-1})=(n-2)(b_n-b_{n-1})$$

Denoting $c_n:=b_{n+1}-b_n$, we have,

$$c_n=(n-2)c_{n-1}\implies c_n=(n-2)!c_2$$

But $c_2=(2-2)c_1=0$ and hence $c_n=0$ for all $n$ which implies $b_{n+1}=b_n$ for all $n$, i.e., the sequence $(b_n)$ is a constant, so $b_n=b_0=a_0$ and thus $a_n=\dfrac{b_n}{n!}=\dfrac{a_0}{n!}$

---

It's now obvious that the required limit is $0$ since $a_0$ is a constant while $n!$ grows unbounded as $n\to\infty$, so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_0}{n!}= 0$